# xPages label onclick event doesn't work on white spaces

Tags: javascript, html, xpages

I have a simple label:

```
<xp:label value="My Label                       " id="label2" style="width:350.0px">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script>
            <![CDATA[xxxxxxxxxx;]]>
        </xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:label>
```

So I need onclick event execute when I click either on label text or on white space next to label text. This code works only when I click on label text "My Label" either I add a style size or whitespase itself to the label value.

Comment: Try using &nbsp; instead of spaces

Comment: sorry.. I forgot to mention that I did try &nbsp; as well.. It doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `<xp:label>` renders a `<span>` or `label` element which are inline elements.

You might add `display:inline-block` into the `style` to turn it into a block element.